# Erase data or reformat NFC tag

Tags: android, xamarin.android, nfc

Is there a way to erase data or reformat NFC tags? I have a limited number of tags and I want to be able to reformat them for testing.

I'm looking for something like [NXP Tag Writer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter&hl=en)'s Clean function in it's Professional edition.

Comment: And by reformat I am guessing you'd like to unformat them?

Comment: Yes. Any idea how to unformat them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the tag type and the chip inside whether this is possible. A formatted Type 2 Tag cannot be undone (some bytes are write-once). A Type 3 Tag can also not be unformatted by the end-user. A DESFire tag as Type 4 Tag can be unformatted if you know the necessary authentication keys. The same holds for MIFARE Classic tags. I think a Type 1 Tag can be unformatted by overwriting it with zeroes. Same for an ICODE tag.

Comment: So there is no method in the Android SDK to unformat the Tags?

Comment: Correct. You will have to write your own code for tags that can be unformatted.

Comment: What I did was just write a blank string and check for that on my app.